# java Generics T extends abc

Tags: java, generics

I saw a method

`protected <T extends ABC> T save( T Acd, boolean en) {`

It should return any sub type of ABC.

In this case, why not simply just use ABC?

`protected ABC save(ABC Acd, boolean en) {`

Comment: The person that wrote the code decided that it should be that way. `extends` makes it more flexible in some cases. And T over ABC in this case lets you use a more specific (sub type of ABC) return type.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is in the return value. Given that `Foo extends ABC`.

First version allows you to write

`Foo f = save(someFoo, true);`

The second version would require you to cast explicitly

`Foo f = (Foo) save(someFoo, true);`